# Missing object loop through json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

http://jsfiddle.net/ow9g9y0d/

```
var item = {
        "slots": [{
            "id": "3",
                "name": "a"
        }, {
            "id": "1",
                "name": "b"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
                "name": "b"
        }]
};
var data = {};

item.slots.forEach(function(i){
    if( i["name"] == "b"){
    data["b"] = i;
    }else{
    data["a"] = i;
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

I have 2 items that the name is not equal to b, but they appear only once under 'a', what happened right there?

Comment: Your first "b" value is overwritten by second one. What you need to do ?

Comment: No, you have **one** item whose name is not equal to "b".

Comment: `data[i["name"]] = i;`

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu I expect all of the 'b' goes under 'b'. How to avoid the overwrite problem?

Comment: @JamesLemon In that case, you need to create array if there are multiple data with same "name"

Comment: @JqueryKing Still it will be overwritten

Comment: create array inside the loop?

Comment: @JqueryKing nope it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
var item = {
  "slots": [{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "a"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "b"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "b"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "b"
  }]
};
var data = {};
var ctr = 0;
item.slots.forEach(function(i) {
  if (i.name == "b") {
    (!(data.b == undefined)) ? ctr++ : data.b = {};
    data.b["" + ctr] = i;
  } else {
    data.a = i;
  }
});

console.log(data);
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.b);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
var item = {
        "slots": [{
            "id": "3",
                "name": "a"
        }, {
            "id": "1",
                "name": "b"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
                "name": "b"
        }]
};
var data = {}, temp;

item.slots.forEach(function(i){

    var temp = data[i["name"]];

    if (temp) {
        if (!(temp instanceof Array)) {
            data[i["name"]] = [temp];
        }
        data[i["name"]].push(i);
    } else {
        data[i["name"]] = i;
    }

});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Make sure you add a check else array will be recreated

Comment: some value? where is it?

Comment: can the array be object instead at the end?

Comment: this is not what I want.

Comment: @JamesLemon If you want object then it should have a unique key. Is it okay if we use "id" as key ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/RamVanamali/4611adk0/

```js
var item = {
    "slots": [{
        "id": "3",
            "name": "a"
    }, {
        "id": "1",
            "name": "b"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
            "name": "b"
    }]
};
var arr = [];
item.slots.forEach(function (i) {
    var data = {};
    if (i["name"] == "b") {
        data["b"] = i;
    } else {
        data["a"] = i;
    }

    arr.push(data);
});
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

Result:
[{"a":{"id":"3","name":"a"}},{"b":{"id":"1","name":"b"}},{"b":{"id":"2","name":"b"}}]